# display only duplicate record from multiple tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to display only duplicate records in the output.
I have 4 tables -->

```
Batch_tab
```

BtachId-------CourseName-------PaperName-------PaperCode-------Sem

```
BatchItems_tab
```

BatchItemID-------BatchId(Fk)-------RegisterNum

```
Sheet_tab
```

BatchId-------SheetID-------BatchNum

```
ShhetItems_tab
```

SheetItemId-------SheetId-------BatchId-------Marks

Suppose there are 4 Papers named as "Java" but the PaperCode differs than its not duplicate. Its duplicate only if a particular RegisterNum has multiple PaperCodes.
I tried with group by clause but it didn't work.
it will be very grateful if any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well - if you start by providing a correct table structure so we can see how tables are connected it will help. But essentially what you need to do is join your tables together, then you can use the `row_number() partition by` or `group by` / `count` to get a row count per group and then select those where that number is larger than one.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is how the table structure is.

Comment: I have tried with this query but doesn't work

Comment: select
B.PaperCode,
BI.ReviewedRegNo,
count(*) as Dup
from Batch_tab B
join BatchItems_tab BI ON B.BatchId = BI.BatchId
group by PaperCode, RegisterNum
having count(*) > 1